# Does doing calculations inside each document incur any cost in cloud functions?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently trying to create a post-ranking system for my app.

I don't even know if this works but what I'm trying to do is every few minutes, I'm going to run a cloud function that goes through each document in my firestore collections, do some calculations with the fields in the documents and if the result of that calculation is a certain number, I'm going to add it to the popular post collection.

I'm wondering if doing the calculation for each document is allowed and if it is, I'm wondering if there are costs incurred in them (do they cost as reading). Or do you have more sufficient answer to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you intend to read the documents, those will be charged as document reads. The write(s) will be charged as document writes. And then of course the Cloud Function itself will cost.

All of these charges are explained on the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), so I recommend doing some back-of-the-napkin calculations there, possibly using the pricing calculator near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Okay, what if I just store that calculation inside the field. Wouldn't that mean I do not have to read the documents since I am just trying to query and order documents by 10 (for example) highest number for that field? Then, I'm assuming that would only result in 10 document reads?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you need to read 10 documents and write 1 document for the calculation, you will be charged for 10 document reads, and 1 document write each time the code runs (since the Node.js/Admin SDK doesn't cache results).